# Bootstrapping Nest.js dependency tree for executable script (without a server)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Is it possible to run a service in an executable file? 
Looking to simply "bootstrap" a module and call a service method directly

```
const userService = new UserService()
userService.find(1).then(console.log)
```

But I'd need all the dependencies to be hooked up, and the database started.

`typedi` allows you to `getContainer` which handles this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core'
import { AppModule } from 'app/AppModule'
import { ContactCore } from 'domain/contact/ContactCore'
import { ContactModule } from 'domain/contact/ContactModule'

(async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: {
      origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:6006'],
      credentials: true
    }
  })
  const contactCore = app.select(ContactModule).get(ContactCore)

  const resolve = await contactCore.read({ uuid: "550718e8-4137-46c0-a90c-2abc6c4d96e2" })

  console.log(resolve)

})()
```